# Custom Post Type permalink shows wrong page: homepage/index.php

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

Hello I am working on a project where I need to have custom post types.
Creating the post types and making them show up in my admin menu was a walk in the park using the following:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'Portfolio',
        array(
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail','excerpt'), 
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Portfolio' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Portfolio' ),
                            ),
        'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'), 
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
```

I have created a number of custom posts and all of them get their own perma link.

```
http://www.mydomain.com/subdomain/?p=123
```

Resulting in

```
http://www.mydomain.com/subdomain/?custom-post-type=post-title
```

However whenever I view **this permalink** it **loads my index.php** file instead of the custom post belonging to this link. 
The **same happens** when I try to load `http://www.mydomain.com/subdomain/custom-post-type` to access the **archive** page: it **loads my index.php** file.

I already tried the following:

- Visiting the permalink setting within wordpress
- Deleting all pages with slug in common width my custom pages
- Deleting all categories with name in common with my custom pages

leads:

- I have **no custom taxonomy** as far as i know. So I did not register any. I only have a custom meta box with radio buttons being saved to the post meta
- I called: `require_once(ABSPATH .'wp-includes/pluggable.php');` to solve an issue with the post meta

conclusion:
I did all this without success. Have been looking for a solution for more than a day now. So i guess it's time to call in the reinforcements. Does anyone have a clue how to solve this and save my day? Thanks in advance!

Comment: change post type Portfolio to portfolio `register_post_type($post_type, $args);` $post_type (string) (required) Post type. (max. 20 characters, can not contain capital letters or spaces)

Answer (score 1):

post_type needs to be max. 20 characters, can not contain capital letters or spaces, in `register_post_type();` function your post type name is capitalize **Portfolio** replace with lower letters **portfolio**

this is my register post type snippet, follow it

```
// add action register our post type portfolio
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_portfolio' );

// Register our Custom Post type as portfolio
function register_cpt_portfolio() {

    // labels text for our post type portfolio
    $labels = array(
        // post type general name
        'name' => __( 'Portfolio' ),
        // post type singular name
        'singular_name' => __( 'Portfolio Item' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New Portfolio Item' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Portfolio Item' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Portfolio Item' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Portfolio Item' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Portfolio Item' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Portfolio Items' ),
        'not_found' =>  __( 'No Portfolio Items found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Portfolio Items found in Trash' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Portfolio'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'author', ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio-item', 'with_front' => false )
    );  
    register_post_type( 'portfolio' , $args );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I will work with this for now. I'll let you know how it turns out!

Comment: Please explain how this code is different from the OP's, why it works, and why the OP's doesn't work.

Comment: @Chip Bennett i have edited my answer with some information why their (asker) code was not working.

Comment: Anjum, I fixed the issue. Thanks for your help. I used your code since i'm quite new to wordpress coding and your code was very understandable. However it did not quite solve the issue. I was writing my own plugin and somewhere in that plugin i wrote the following: 'if(is_admin())'. That very line there made my pages unavailable but it did make them show up in my admin menu. Totally ignorant of me to ignore the fact that i wrote that line in this problem. I am grateful for your help! I will edit my post with the final details for anyone stumbling upon this question!